# Dynamically updating a ListView from JSON object using a custom ListViewAdapter

Tags: json, listview, dynamic, custom-controls, listview-adapter

As usual the question comes from a first time user of Android. Its three weeks later and im tearing my hair out will do my best to explain the problem.

Firstly I am using Exlipse 3.7.1 and SDK r15 as of today because I thought Ill try upgrade maybe thats whats causing the issues but seems to be the same while using r13.

Here is a working copy of my code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/ibHome"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"        
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/trophy_cup" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/lblHome"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/helloHome"
            android:textColor="@color/txtYellow"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width="1dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@null"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/ibQuit"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"  
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/yellow_flag" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- Body code goes here -->        

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.17"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:text="Top"
            android:textColor="@color/txtYellow"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingTop="7dp" android:typeface="serif"/>

        <Spinner
            android:entries="@array/strArrTop"
            android:id="@+id/spinTop"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.44"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:longClickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- End Body code goes here -->    

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblWidth"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView           
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_width="201dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ddo_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeight"            
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

mylist.xml (the custom list adapter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:textColor="@color/txtYellow" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@color/txtYellow" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest file, uses minSDK 8.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hunta.DDOFastestTimes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <supports-screens 
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".DDOFastestTimesActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and finally the offending java file:

```
package com.hunta.DDOFastestTimes;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DDOFastestTimesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** JSON variables */
String jc1, jc2 = null;
/** END JSON variables */

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /** JSON variables */
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        /** END JSON variables */

        ImageButton closeApp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibQuit);
        closeApp.setOnClickListener(this);

        /** http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=1 */
            /** Populating the spinner from that string-array */
            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinTop );             
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.strArrTop, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
            /** END Populating the spinner from that string-array */

            /** Create a reference to our spinner */        
            s.setAdapter( adapter );
            /** END Create a reference to our spinner */
        /** END http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=1 */

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());    

        /** JSON code to initiate the php */
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          //http post
          try{
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://url-to-my-php-file/fastag.php");
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           is = entity.getContent();
           }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
              }
          //convert response to string
          try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
         sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
         String line="0";
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          is.close();
          result=sb.toString();
          }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                  }
          //paring data

          JSONArray jArray;
          try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data=null;

                // Adding the JSON data to the list view
                int length = jArray.length();

                List<String> listContents1 = new ArrayList<String>(length);
                List<String> listContents2 = new ArrayList<String>(length);

                // Convert ListString Array to an ArrayList
                ArrayList<tblRecord> arrTxt = new ArrayList<tblRecord>();               

                // Changing the ListViews               
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jc1 = json_data.getString("c1");
                    jc2 = json_data.getString("c2");

                    listContents1.add(json_data.getString("c1"));
                    listContents2.add(json_data.getString("c2"));

                    // Create an Array to pass to our custom view
                    tblRecord addRecord = new tblRecord(jc1, jc2);
                    arrTxt.add(addRecord);
                }

        ListView myListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        myListView1.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrTxt));

        // END Adding the JSON data to the list view

        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Results Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** END JSON code to initiate the php */

    }
    /** End Called when the activity is first created. */

    /** Using a custom List View */
    public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tblRecord> {
        private ArrayList<tblRecord> arrList;

        public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<tblRecord> arrList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, arrList);
            this.arrList = arrList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
            }

            tblRecord user = arrList.get(position);
            if (user != null) {
                TextView c1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView c2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

                if (c1 != null) {
                    c1.setText(user.c1);
                }

                if(c2 != null) {
                    c2.setText(user.c2);
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    public class tblRecord {
        public String c1;
        public String c2;

        public tblRecord(String c1, String c2) {
            this.c1 = c1;
            this.c2 = c2;
        }
    }

    /** END Using a custom List View */

    /** Listener for the spinner, we will handle changes made to the spinner here */
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View v, int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The top " +
              parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    /** END Listener for the spinner, we will handle changes made to the spinner here */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        // Intent myIntent;
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.ibQuit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Up until this point everything is working, if not 100% at least it works but now I need to try dynamically change the contents of the list view when the user changes the spinner.

The emulator uses -dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in its run configuration
I am running 3.7in WVGA

Now after an 8 hour attempt to find a way to do this, this is as far as I have gotten but it just crashes:

```
package com.hunta.DDOFastestTimes;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class DDOFastestTimesActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
private UserItemAdapter myAdapter;
private ArrayList<tblRecord> arrTxt = null;
private Runnable viewJSON;

/** JSON variables */
String jc1, jc2, result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
/** END JSON variables */

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageButton closeApp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibQuit);
        closeApp.setOnClickListener(this);

        /** http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=1 */
            /** Populating the spinner from that string-array */
            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinTop );             
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.strArrTop, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
            /** END Populating the spinner from that string-array */

            /** Create a reference to our spinner */        
            s.setAdapter( adapter );
            /** END Create a reference to our spinner */
        /** END http://www.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=1 */

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());    

        arrTxt = new ArrayList<tblRecord>();
        this.myAdapter = new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.mylist, arrTxt);
        setListAdapter(this.myAdapter);
        viewJSON = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arrTxt = MyJSONFetch(0);
            }
        };
        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewJSON, "MagentoBackground");
        thread.start();     

        ListView myListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        myListView1.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrTxt));         

    }
    /** End Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(arrTxt != null && arrTxt.size() > 0){
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<arrTxt.size();i++)
                myAdapter.add(arrTxt.get(i));
            }
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };       
    /** Using a custom List View */
    public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tblRecord> {
        private ArrayList<tblRecord> arrTxt;

        public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<tblRecord> arrTxt) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, arrTxt);
            this.arrTxt = arrTxt;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
            }

            tblRecord user = arrTxt.get(position);
            if (user != null) {
                TextView c1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView c2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);

                if (c1 != null) {
                    c1.setText(user.c1);
                }

                if(c2 != null) {
                    c2.setText(user.c2);
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }

    public class tblRecord {
        public String c1;
        public String c2;

        public tblRecord(String c1, String c2) {
            this.c1 = c1;
            this.c2 = c2;
        }
    }
    /** END Using a custom List View */

    /** Reload JSON Database from onclick listener */
    public ArrayList<tblRecord> MyJSONFetch(int position) 
    {
    ArrayList<tblRecord> arrTxt = new ArrayList<tblRecord>();
    String tmpUrl = null;
        /** JSON code to initiate the php */
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          //http post
          try{
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               switch (position)
               {
               case 0:
                   tmpUrl = "http://smutlow.comp-degree.uhi.ac.uk/UG409713/DDOFastestTimes/fastag.php";
                   break;
               case 1:
                   tmpUrl = "http://smutlow.comp-degree.uhi.ac.uk/UG409713/DDOFastestTimes/fastas.php";
                   break;
               }
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(tmpUrl);   
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           is = entity.getContent();
           }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
              }
          //convert response to string
          try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
         sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
         String line="0";
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          is.close();
          result=sb.toString();
          }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                  }
          //paring data

          JSONArray jArray;
          try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data=null;

                // Adding the JSON data to the list view
                int length = jArray.length();

                List<String> listContents1 = new ArrayList<String>(length);
                List<String> listContents2 = new ArrayList<String>(length);        

                // Changing the ListViews               
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jc1 = json_data.getString("c1");
                    jc2 = json_data.getString("c2");

                    listContents1.add(json_data.getString("c1"));
                    listContents2.add(json_data.getString("c2"));

                    // Create an Array to pass to our custom view
                    tblRecord addRecord = new tblRecord(jc1, jc2);
                    arrTxt.add(addRecord);
                }

        // END Adding the JSON data to the list view        
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Results Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();           
    }
    /** END Reload JSON Database from onclick listener */
    runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    return arrTxt;

}  

    /** Listener for the spinner, we will handle changes made to the spinner here */
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View v, int position, long id) {
            MyJSONFetch(position);
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The top " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MyJSONFetch(position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }

    }

    /** END Listener for the spinner, we will handle changes made to the spinner here */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        // Intent myIntent;
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.ibQuit:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically Ive tried to seperate the JSON code from the onCreate and put it into its own public method so I can call it from the MyOnItemSelectedListener but I am out of ideas and have demonstrated my total lack of understanding of java.

Please if you respond try be a simplistic as possible with your answer.

Thank you in advance.

p.s. apologies if the layout isn't what it should be this is my first post

Comment: Could you describe in words what your problem is, as it isn't really clear from the question?

Comment: ok how can i fire the json code to initiate the php dbquery based on the item selected in the MyOnItemSelectedListener of the spinner, then poplate the custom list with my JSON object data.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question I lack the understanding of some basic principles to properly express my intent here, please bear with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution to this perhaps someone might offer a better one but here is what I did:

Rather than try to fire the PHP I needed from the spinner I opted to use the spinner to load a new Intent with the relevant URL to the PHP I wanted to use added to a Bundle.

```
if (position == 0) {
   Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
   Intent myIntent;
   myBundle.putString("myPHP", "http://url-to-my-php-file/fastag.php");
   myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DDOFastestGuilds.class);
   myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
   startActivity(myIntent); 
   onLowMemory();
   finish();
}
```

I then added two new .java files practically identical to the first one, adding two lines at the start:

```
Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String tmpPHP =  myBundle.getString("myPHP");
```

I amended the line that calls the HttpPost to point to the variable I just created tmpPHP rather than the literal URL I had used in the original file:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(tmpPHP);
```

And lastly changing the spinners selection to reflect that last selected by the user, if there were more than two options in the spinner I would have used the bundle to pass the last selected index but in my example I only had two options so I knew the selected index was either 0 or 1 depending on the Intent i wanted to open. (Making sure its directly after the setAdapter method):

```
s.setSelection(1);
```

Hoping for an alternative method going forward.
If anyone can suggest a way to only have to use one Activity to get the same result I would be grateful.